# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on Server 2012 - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition SP2 on Windows 2012 server.

The error is:

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its complaining about the userSettings section of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.LandingPage.Properties.Settings file

Run below command :

`rd /s /q %localappdata%\Microsoft_Corporation`

Refer [connect item](https://web.archive.org/web/20131124071802/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/758332/an-error-occurred-creating-the-configuration-section-handler-for-usersettings-microsoft-sqlserver-configuration-landingpage-properties-settings-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-version-4-0-0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/smondal/an-error-occurred-creating-the-configuration-section-handler-for-usersettingsmicrosoft-sqlserver-configuration-landingpage-properties-settings) for more details on resolving it.